# Google geolocation doesn´t work in mobile browsers

Tags: geolocation, google-geocoding-api

the standard geolocation code from google does not work in mobile browsers (Android Chrome, standard Android browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
}
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         alert(results[2].address_components[0].long_name) 

        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

</body>
</html>
```

But in Desktop Browser it works fine... Why? I´m sure the code has worked a few days ago. I didn´t change anything. is it possible that google has changed something in their code?

EDIT: it´s important for me to get the location with GPS, WLAN AND! mobile network

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the **`sensor`** parameter to `true` like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Go through **[Geolocation documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation)** of Google maps API.

> **Specifying the Sensor Parameter**
>
> Use of the Google Maps API requires that you indicate whether your
>   application is using a sensor (such as a GPS locator) to determine the
>   user's location. This is **especially important for mobile devices.**
>   Applications must pass a required sensor parameter to the  tag
>   when including the Maps API javascript code, indicating whether or not
>   your application is using a sensor device.
>
> ***Applications that determine the user's location via a sensor must pass
>   sensor=true when loading the Maps API JavaScript.***

Hope you understand.

Comment: yeah i understand and now it works with the GPS sensor and only when i turn GPS on. But it must be possible to get the location with WLAN or mobile signal.

Comment: @m1crdy Geolocation fully depends on users.  You can't force it, right.  That why if you check in desktop browser, it will show a popup for sharing the current location.  Whereas in mobile it uses GPS tracker.  Either wifi or mobile signal.  Hope you got my point.

Comment: but if users activated location with mobile signal or wifi it has to be possible to locate the user without GPS. eg. the facebook app does exactly that!

Comment: Geolocation provides location information for the device, such as latitude and longitude. Common sources of location information include Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs.

This is described in PhoneGap API as well.